# Can I send Notification using job scheduler?

Tags: android, android-notifications, jobservice

I'm trying to have Notification very time the Job service run. It's not working. I want to know the right way of providing notification when the Job service is enabled. Please help me in understanding these concepts and how to make it work?
**Note**: Scheduling is working, I'm trying to add Notification, which is not working.

```
public class GuardianJobService  extends JobService{
     public final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1001;
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    enableTracking();
    addNotification();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return true;
}

private void addNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Notifications Example")
                    .setContentText("This is a test notification");
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
public void enableTracking() {  
    ......
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some potential problems

- Forgot to add GuardianJobService in AndroidManifest.xml
- Never meet the condition to run the job (could you show your schedule code?)
- If you run on device with Android >= 8.0, you need to create Notification Channel in order to receive notification (refer [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification))

Comment: Scheduling is working fine, But Notification is not working

Comment: I tried your notification code and it works fine in my device (Android 6). If you are using Android >= 8.0. You should create notification channel. Else, could you try to use some random notification id instead of zero "manager.notify(random_notification_id_here, builder.build());"

Answer (score 1):

Job scheduling is basically to run long task in background.  You    should add the notification in **FirebaseMessagingService** and then start the job to do task in background after adding notification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I’ve implemented the listener which is scheduled to check for a event. If that meets my requirement then I just call the given below function.

```
private void generateBigTextStyleNotification() {
    String notificationChannelId =
            NotificationUtil.createNotificationChannel(thisService);

    String title = "Your title";
    String msg = "Your message";

    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(msg)
            .setBigContentTitle(title)
            .setSummaryText("Your Summary");

    PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    thisService,
                    0,
                    new Intent(),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
            );

    //Build and issue the notification.

    // Notification Channel Id is ignored for Android pre O (26).
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompatBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    thisService, notificationChannelId);
    notificationCompatBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    GlobalNotificationBuilder.setNotificationCompatBuilderInstance(notificationCompatBuilder);
    Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
            + "://" + thisService.getPackageName() + "YourSoundPath");
    Notification notification = notificationCompatBuilder
            // BIG_TEXT_STYLE sets title and content for API 16 (4.1 and after).
            .setStyle(bigTextStyle)
            // Title for API <16 (4.0 and below) devices.
            .setContentTitle(title)
            // Content for API <24 (7.0 and below) devices.
            .setContentText(msg)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    thisService.getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL)
            // Set primary color (important for Wear 2.0 Notifications).
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(thisService, R.color.secondary_background_color))
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_EVENT)

            // Sets priority for 25 and below. For 26 and above, 'priority' is deprecated for
            // 'importance' which is set in the NotificationChannel. The integers representing
            // 'priority' are different from 'importance', so make sure you don't mix them.
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)

            // Sets lock-screen visibility for 25 and below. For 26 and above, lock screen
            // visibility is set in the NotificationChannel.
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setAutoCancel(true)

            // Adds additional actions specified above.
            .build();
    mNotificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
```

[Bahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5832543/bahman) Thanks for asking, Here is our NotificationUtil class:

```
public class NotificationUtil {
public static String createNotificationChannel(
        Context context) {

    // NotificationChannels are required for Notifications on O (API 26) and above.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        // The id of the channel.
        String channelId = "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID";

        // The user-visible name of the channel.
        CharSequence channelName = "YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME";
        // The user-visible description of the channel.
        String channelDescription = "YOUR_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION";
        int channelImportance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        int channelLockscreenVisibility = NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC;

        // Initializes NotificationChannel.
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = null;
        notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, channelImportance);

        notificationChannel.setDescription(channelDescription);
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(channelLockscreenVisibility);

        // Adds NotificationChannel to system. Attempting to create an existing notification
        // channel with its original values performs no operation, so it's safe to perform the
        // below sequence.
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        return channelId;
    } else {
        // Returns null for pre-O (26) devices.
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is NotificationUtil? Android studio is complaining about it.

Comment: @Bahman I added the NotificationUtil class as well. Happy Coding!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please create a Notification Channel and register it with your Notification Manager. Use the same notification channel when building a notification. If you are running your code on a device with Android version greater than or equal to Oreo, the app won't trigger a notification, hence you need to have a notification channel for versions Oreo and greater. Refer: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification